# What is that font

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I want to know what is that font?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Savoye](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/savoye/) from myfonts.com, I think the question font is slightly slanted.

[image]

Comment: Savoye came up as the second possibility when going through the questionnaire at http://www.identifont.com - that is http://www.identifont.com/identify?16+flowers+97+5NZ+3C+1QN+7UH+58D+IQ6+6E+J+5NV+JIR+20+PAH+2V+9Y

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher It's right